# A script can run in Pycharm, but when run in cmd, there is no reaction

Tags: python

write a python script, it can run in pycharm successfully, but when it runs in cmd, it doesn't work, without any errors reported.

When it runs in Pycharm, it shows the expected output:

Screenshot 1

[image]

When it runs in cmd it shows a blank Tk window:

Screenshot 2

[image]

When it runs in cmd, it only has the gui, not any content.

Here is code:

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests,codecs,urllib,sys
import codecs
from Tkinter import  *
import time,datetime,winsound


def code(text):
    text='外贸'
    url_gbk = urllib.quote(text.decode(sys.stdin.encoding).encode('gbk'))

    return url_gbk

def get(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        return response.text
    except EOFError:
    print 'error'

def makesoup(response):
    list=[]
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'lxml')
    soup = soup.find_all(attrs='li',class_='seaList13')
    for i in soup:
         list.append(i.text)
    return list


def get_yao_xian_shi_de_( i ):
    yi_cun_zai=[]
    yao_xian_shi_de_ = []
    txt = codecs.open(r'D:\yuyao\.idea\txt.txt','a+','utf-8')

yi_cun_zai = [k.strip() for k in txt]
txt.close()
txt = codecs.open(r'D:\yuyao\.idea\txt.txt','a+','utf-8')

text    = '外贸'
text    = code(text)
url     = 'http://www.yyrc.com/job/?     JobType=0&WorkPlace=0&Trade=0&Property=0&' \
          'JobProperty=0&Degree=0&WorkYears=0&Sex=0&MonthPay=0&' \
          'PublishDate=0&Key='+text+'&Orderid=0&Styleid=2&PageNo='+str(i)
response = get(url)
list_1=makesoup(response)
list_1= list(set(list_1))

for j in list_1:
        if(j in yi_cun_zai):
            pass
        else:
            print j
            yao_xian_shi_de_.append(j)
            txt.write(j+'\r\n')
txt.close()
return yao_xian_shi_de_

def on_go():
    root = Tk()
    t    = Text(root)
    t.pack()
    for i in range(5):
        xian_shi_wo  =   get_yao_xian_shi_de_(i)
        for j in xian_shi_wo:
            winsound.Beep(500,500)
            t.insert(INSERT,j+'        ')
            t.insert(INSERT,str(time.ctime())+'\n\r')
            t.mark_set('insert', 1.0)
            t.update()
            time.sleep(0.1)
    t.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    on_go()
```

`

Comment: What versions of python are your cmd prompt and pycharm running? It's likely they aren't the same

Comment: I am sure that they use the same Interpreter of python2.7